# Some users no longer appear in "@" autocomplete in Gitlab Markdown text fields

Tags: gitlab, markdown

In GitLab, when writing text in fields, you can type "@" and the beginning of a person's name. An autocomplete list of matching people appears, and you can select a name.

GitLab help refers to this feature as a "Special GitLab references" in their superset of Markdown. They call it a "specific user" reference.

Recently, this feature has stopped working when typing the names of people in group *X*. That is, their names do not show up in the list after typing "@".

We have not adjusted the rights or permissions of group *X*. Also, keep in mind, the people in group *X* have not reported a change in their access levels. This is just an impact to their names showing up when "@"-ing them in text fields.

Our internal GitLab instance was recently updated to 12.6.4-ee. I do not know the previous version.

I am assuming this is a bug in our current version of GitLab. Then again, it might be some security change. I can find no report of the bug in [GitLab issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues?scope=all&search=user%20reference%20markdown&state=opened).

We could start fiddling with the rights and permissions of group *X* but I am wondering if someone else knows precisely what this problem is and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to GitLab Staff this is a known bug, but the fix ([MR 25167](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/25167)) is not merged in yet.

The only solution seems to be to wait until the fix is deployed. There is no work around.

See also [this conversation](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/some-users-no-longer-appear-in-autocomplete-in-text-fields/34590) in GitLab forums.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is somewhat improved with [GitLab 13.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/#search-and-autocomplete-by-full-name-in-comment-mentions) (March 2021)

> ### Search and autocomplete by full name in comment mentions
>
> It’s not common for GitLab users to use their full name as their username.
> This makes it difficult to find the individuals you want to `@` mention because the autocomplete doesn’t do a great job matching both full name or username.
>
> As a first step towards [making autocomplete smarter](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/207134), you can now more easily search for people based on their username or full name.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/autocomplete_characters.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36705).

This is not for markdown yet, but will contribute for making that kind of auto-completion more efficient in general.

---

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#autocomplete-suggestions-for-users-in-the-global-search-bar) (December 2022) proposes another option:

> ### Autocomplete suggestions for users in the global search bar
>
> In the search bar, you can now see [autocomplete suggestions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#autocomplete-suggestions) for users. When you select a user, their profile page appears.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/adds_a_user_category_to_the_autocomplete_results_of_the_search_bar.png -- Autocomplete suggestions for users in the global search bar]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#autocomplete-suggestions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/377530).